# pivot table in specific intervals pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a one column dataframe which looks like this:

```
Neive Bayes
0   8.322087e-07
1   3.213342e-24
2   4.474122e-28
3   2.230054e-16
4   3.957606e-29
5   9.999992e-01
6   3.254807e-13
7   8.836033e-18
8   1.222642e-09
9   6.825381e-03
10  5.275194e-07
11  2.224289e-06
12  2.259303e-09
13  2.014053e-09
14  1.755933e-05
15  1.889681e-04
16  9.929193e-01
17  4.599619e-05
18  6.944654e-01
19  5.377576e-05
```

I want to pivot it to wide format but with specific intervals. The first 9 rows should make up 9 columns of the first row, and continue this pattern until the final table has 9 columns and has 9 times fewer rows than now. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(columns=df.index % 9, index=df.index // 9, values='Neive Bayes')

              0             1             2             3             4  \
0  8.322087e-07  3.213342e-24  4.474122e-28  2.230054e-16  3.957606e-29   
1  6.825381e-03  5.275194e-07  2.224289e-06  2.259303e-09  2.014053e-09   
2  6.944654e-01  5.377576e-05           NaN           NaN           NaN   

          5             6             7             8  
0  0.999999  3.254807e-13  8.836033e-18  1.222642e-09  
1  0.000018  1.889681e-04  9.929193e-01  4.599619e-05  
2       NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct multiindex, `set_index` and `unstack`

```
iix = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.arange(df.shape[0]) // 9, 
                                 np.arange(df.shape[0]) % 9])

df_wide = df.set_index(iix)['Neive Bayes'].unstack()

Out[204]:
              0             1             2             3             4  \
0  8.322087e-07  3.213342e-24  4.474122e-28  2.230054e-16  3.957606e-29
1  6.825381e-03  5.275194e-07  2.224289e-06  2.259303e-09  2.014053e-09
2  6.944654e-01  5.377576e-05           NaN           NaN           NaN

          5             6             7             8
0  0.999999  3.254807e-13  8.836033e-18  1.222642e-09
1  0.000018  1.889681e-04  9.929193e-01  4.599619e-05
2       NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN
```